# how to change Mybean in "Type type = new TypeToken<List<Mybean>>(){}.getType()" to be a parameter?

Tags: java, json, generics

I use below code to convert jsonString to collection.

```
    public static List<Itembean> getData(String jsonString){
          Gson gson = new Gson();
          Type type = new TypeToken<List<Itembean>>(){}.getType();

          return gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);     
    }
```

The problem is there are serval beans, so how to modify those code to make it can be called by all than to copy/paste and modify the bean name.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the example to TypeToken.where() which seems to solve your kind of problem, see http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html#where%28com.google.common.reflect.TypeParameter,%20java.lang.Class%29

Answer (score 1):

```
public static <T> List<T> getData(String jsonString, Class<T> classType){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<T>>(){}.getType();
    List<T> list =  gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
    return list;
}
```

---

```
getData(gsonString, Itembean.class);
getData(gsonString, Itembean1.class);
getData(gsonString, Itembean2.class);
```